# SSRS - Use the result from one textbox to populate a field from a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am writing a report in SSRS. Can i use the text result from a textbox to pull a Field from one of my datasets?
For example:

In Textbox1, i have the formula =First(Fields!Metric1.Value, "Dataset2") which produces the text result: "BikeSales" in Textbox1

I need an expression in Textbox2 that references a Field called BikeSales in DataSet1  based on the result. Something like: =Sum(Fields.("Text from Textbox1").Value, "Dataset1") to pull the Field from Dataset 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is reference the Textbox1 value.. you can use `Reportitems!Textbox1.value`

If you want the value from the actual dataset, you can use `lookup`

Comment: is there a "vlookup" type function like in excel?

Comment: yes.. it is called Lookup. in the expression builder look for -  Common functions -> Miscellaneous -... =Lookup(Fields!SaleProdId.Value, Fields!ProductID.Value,  Fields!Name.Value, "Product") (for example)